# Yii2 - Validating nested objects

Tags: yii, yii2

Here's a question about a topic that Ive been thinking about for a while.

In Yii2, it is recommended generally to create Form Models for your requests. Rules are added to those models to validate the input. An example is the EntryForm in the Yii2 guide

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class EntryForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

My problem is, when we have nested objects. An example is a form for creating **Customer** with multiple **Branches**. If **Customer** and **Branch** are two separate models, but both get submitted in one form, what is the best option for validating input from such a nested form. Bear in mind that here the input is nested. Example:

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "vat_no": "12345678",
  "time_zone": 277,
  "category": 1,
  "email": "customer@mycustomer.com",
  "stores":[
    {
        "name": "store1",
        "phone": 1234567
    },
    {
        "name": "store2",
        "phone": 2345678
    }
]
}
```

Comment: you can still use the formmodel to add all your rules in that model rather than the Base model and both the models are validated via FormModel simple as that.

Comment: means you can list down all the validation rules in `FormModel` and your `Customer` and `Address` model can be clean with basic rules which define the fields  as `safe` , `strings` , `integer` or `required`

Comment: I'll edit the question to mention some other scenario that I should have mentioned :D

Comment: This is the example that I meant @MuhammadOmerAslam, but I wasnot clear when I first asked :)

Comment: rob006 has posted the answer below  it provides the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple cases you may use one model and custom validator inside of your form model:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        // ...
        ['stores', 'validateStores'],
    ];
}

public function validateStores() {
    $phoneValidator = new StringValidator(); // use real validators
    $nameValidator = new StringValidator(); // use real validators
    foreach ($this->stores as $store) {
        if (!$phoneValidator->validate($store['phone'], $error)) {
            $this->addError('stores', $error);
            return; // stop on first error
        }
        if (!$nameValidator->validate($store['name'], $error)) {
            $this->addError('stores', $error);
            return; // end on first error
        }
    }
}
```

`validateStores()` may be extracted to separate validator class, then you may also use [`EachValidator`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator) instead of `foreach`.

---

For more complicated nested models you should probably create separate `StoreForm` model for stores (so you will have nested form models), and call `validate()` on children.

```
/**
 * @var StoreForm[]
 */
public $stores;

public function rules() {
    return [
        // ...
        ['stores', 'validateStores'],
    ];
}

public function validateStores() {
    foreach ($this->stores as $store) {
        if (!$store->validate()) {
            $this->addError('stores', 'Stores config is incorrect.');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. But one more question here :)
How much do you think that I should rely on the original model validation? In this example those would be Customer and Branch

Comment: It is hard to say, it really depends on application, so there is no one right answer here. In one app I don't even have a validation in AR and everything is validated in form models. Sometimes AR is enough and you don't need form model.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I really like this approach. I'll try it :D