# Yii2 - ActiveRecord Validation vs Form Validation

Tags: yii2

This is a question about best practices. In general, when is it better to use Form Validation (i.e: Create a form for the request being sent). And when is it better to rely on the ActiveRecord validation.

Example: I have a model **Customer** and model **Address** where each customer has more than one address. In the form to create Customer, I want to send more than one address

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "vat_no": "12345678",
  "time_zone": 277,
  "category": 1,
  "email": "customer@mycustomer.com",
  "addresses":[
    {
        "street_address": "abcd...",
        "phone": 1234567
    },
    {
        "street_address": "hdhdh...",
        "phone": 2345678
    }
]}
```

- Is it better in this case to build a model for this form as in the example given by Yii2 guide here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-forms
- Or is it better to rely on **Customer** and **Address** validations as given in this example https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-multiple-models

**This is a question inspired by a previous question that I asked here [Yii2 - Validating nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721996/yii2-validating-nested-objects), and specifically about the answer given there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It partly depends how closely your form aligns to your models - e.g., how much will you need to transform the form data, are the validation rules the same and how many models are required.

In your case, if there are only 2 models and the logic is pretty clear that the primary model is **Customer** and secondary is **Address**, it's really personal preference. You could use a [scenario](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios) for the form and have scenario-specific rules in the existing models *or* in a dedicated Form model. If, for whatever reason, the form fields have different validation requirements than the database, it might be cleaner to have them in a separate model.

Ultimately the code has to go somewhere, so you want to think about what's going to make the most sense for you to maintain -- e.g., you want to keep data functions out of the controller, so do you want to use the CustomerController or create one for this purpose? If you use a Form model, you might then want a matching controller and keep the primary models focused on table-specific CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a best practice to keep the size of your code base to a minimum.

Thus, if using multiple models works for you, don't create (unnecessary) extra code by adding a form model.